# Using File.applicationStorageDirectory across versions

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I am using File.applicationStorageDirectory to store user data, specifically purchased items from iOS store.

I noticed that when users upgrade their version the data is lost and users need to restore their purchases (on ios items) , is it a bug on my side or is the File.applicationStorageDirectory not the correct place to store that kind of data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

applicationStorageDirectory is also known as the "temporary files" of the system. Regardless of the platform (desktop or mobile) or OS, when something drastic is done (such as installing a new version of the system), those temporary files are (generally) wiped out in the process.

Furthermore, uninstalling your application and reinstalling it (or, indeed, updating it) may (in some cases, dunno about iOS) delete those temporary files, or simply create a NEW directory for them, ignoring the old one.

Third, some cache-cleaning apps will also wipe out this data.

So, to answer your question, yes, you're going to want to store things you want to persist despite major changes, such as in-app purchases, in a new, dedicated folder in the userDirectory or the documentsDirectory.